# How to combine different integers to one

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to do I combine different integers to one to display a result such as 1234567 from

```
print("Enter the first digit")

Digits1 = int(input())

print("Enter the second digit")

Digits2 = int(input())

print("Enter the third digit")

Digits3 = int(input())

print("Enter the fourth digit")

Digits4 = int(input())

print("Enter the fifth digit")

Digits5 = int(input())

print("Enter the sixth digit")

Digits6 = int(input())

print("Enter the final digit")

Digits7 = int(input())

print("The 7 digit code is {0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}".format (Digits1,Digits2,Digits3,Digits4,Digits5,Digits6,Digits7))
```

I do not want all of the digits to be put together in the way that I have done in the print, I want it all to be in one line in one variable.

Comment: Is number of digit fixed? Or it can be any number of digits?

Comment: Only 7 digits. Just different numbers.

Comment: Don't use integers to store the digits unless you plan to do arithmetic with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int(''.join(str(el)
            for el in [Digits1, Digits2, Digits3, Digits4, Digits5, Digits6, Digits7]))
```

Answer (score 1):

use a list instead

```
digit_list = []
print("Enter the first digit")
digit_list_append(str(input()))  # If you gonna join them, keep them as strings
...
# And join them
"".join(digit_list)
```

If you want, you can place the `input` part in a loop and get `n` digits one by one and add them to the list

```
digit_list = []
for _dig in range(1, 8):  # Loop 7 times
    print("Enter {n}th digit:".format(n=_dig))
    digit_list_append(str(input()))
print "".join(digit_list)
```

Comment: +1 for storing as strings. Don't store numbers as a numeric type unless you plan to use them to do arithmetic.

Comment: Exactly, parsing them to `int` and then converting them back to `str' for concatenation is a waste.

Comment: Paring to int does ensure that the user is actually entering numbers though. That said, if they truly only want single digits, the OP should be validating that some other way (regular expressions if they want an extra problem, or sticking with int() and checking the range...)

Comment: Better to `try` a parse to int and an `assert` that the result is of the right length, than to do all that intermediate work and type construction back and forth. Then do as intended, and handle the exceptions as required for erroneous user input.

Comment: Using try-except is better. The OP asks for a good way. I do not consider checking if inputs are digit since this is not a part of the problem. Also OP wants a digit, not a number (so 12 is not a digit but a number). using `str` methods to check the length (`len(x) == 1`) and input type (`x.isdigit()`) would be a better approach. But as I said, they are all different topics.

Answer (score 1):

You can store them all in a string which you concatenate for each digit. So never convert the input to an int.

```
var digits = ''
digits += input()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is basically base-10 problem:

```
number = math.pow(10,6) * Digits7 + math.pow(10,5) * Digits6 + math.pow(10,4) * Digits5 + math.pow(10,3) * Digits4 + math.pow(10,2) * Digits3 + math.pow(10,1) * Digits2 + math.pow(10,0) * Digits1
```

Comment: Oh you were faster. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will mostly work, but will miss a leading zero, and is at least configurable:

```
total=0
count=7
while count > 0:
    print("Enter digit")
    digit = int(input())
    total = total * 10 + digit
    count = count - 1
print("The total is {0}".format(total))
```

Comment: Read the question again, this is not what he wants to do.

Comment: so it would also be correct to output them as a 7-level nested dict? Somehow I don't think `x = {input():{input():{input():{input():{input():{input()}}}}}}` is what he's looking for.

Comment: @machineyearning It's not really clear what the OP wants.  He seems to know he wants number input and he seems to know he wants those numbers connected in what looks like a decimal system and he seems to know he wants the "result" in a single variable.  If you have a better answer then please post it, but ultimately I don't really care about the outcome of this as I have better things to do.

Answer (score 0):

What about [positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Decimal_system) if you prefer integer arithmetic instead of string operations?

```
composed_number = digit_4 * pow(10, 4) \
    + digit_3 * pow(10, 3)  \
    + digit_2 * pow(10, 2)  \
    + digit_1 * pow(10, 1)  \
    + digit_0 * pow(10, 0) \

print(composed_number) # 43210
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would use a list to store the digits, which you could populate in a look like so:

```
number_of_digits = 7
digits = []  # this is an empty list

for i in range(number_of_digits):
    print("Enter digit {0}".format(i))
    digits.append(int(input()))
```

Once you've done that, you can use the str.join function and some list comprehension to join them together:

```
code = "".join(str(x) for x in digits)
print("The {0} digit code is {1}".format(number_of_digits, code))
```

Comment: No need to convert the `input()` to int right away but if you want to add some check, I guess you can ask for digit number `n` until it `isdigit()`.

Comment: I left the int() in because I was assuming that the OP might want to have numbers later on. But you're right, there are better ways to validate the input.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
digists = []
print('enter the digist, input ! to stop.')
num = input()
while num != '!':
    digists.append(num)
    num = input()
i,num = 0,0
for d in reversed(digists):
    num = num + 10**i*int(d)
    i += 1
print(num)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to resolve this e.g.:

- Enter all 7 digits at once:

  ```
  number = int(input('Enter 7 digit number: '))
  ```
- Or put digits in a list:

  ```
  digits = [int(input('Enter the {ordinal} digit: '.format(ordinal=ordinal))
            for ordinal in "first second third fourth fifth sixth final".split()]
  ```

  and convert the list into a number using the decimal position arithmetic
  (`123 = 1*100 + 2*10 + 3 = (1*10 + 2)*10 + 3`):

  ```
  from functools import reduce

  number = reduce(lambda x,y: x*10 + y, digits)
  ```

  or to get the same result using `str`:

  ```
  number = int(''.join(map(str, digits)))
  ```

  Note: if you have to preserve the way the digits are entered now then you could define the `digits` list as:

  ```
  digits = [Digits1, Digits2, Digits3, Digits4, Digits5, Digits6, Digits7]
  ```